# Please destroy this user

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, suggested-edits, spam

A [new (spam user)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4291419/manu) is currently going through my questions and suggesting useless edits:

[image]

As it happens *every edit I reject they just go back and submit their useless suggested edit again, making simply rejecting the suggested edits useless.*

I've stopped rejecting the suggested edits since I know the community will handle the useless edits appropriately.
As *every* edit (hopefully!) will be rejected, this user's going to end up with an edit-ban.

I'd personally like to see this user *banned* since all they're doing is causing an annoyance and are not contributing (positively) to Stack Overflow.

To further justify banning the user, they have started spamming my questions with spam answers:
[image]
[*This is the question.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586675/autoscroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-multiline-textbox/27125573#27125573)

This is going to take some time to clean up (assuming there is no batch delete command for all posts from this user) if this user isn't stopped as soon as possible.

*In the time I wrote this question this user has submitted five more suggested edits, such as [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6313822)*

Comment: Yes there is an edit ban imposed automatically by the system, but this can also be manually done by a moderator if they're made aware of the user's activities.

Comment: I've taken some direct action here on the basis of this question.

Comment: That last suggested edit was made as an anonymous user. Keep rejecting, the system will pick up enough detail to auto-block future attempts soon enough, even if they were to use different IP addresses for each attempt.

Comment: I'm monitoring the review queue, rejecting the spate of posts. My, that user really is going all out to machine-inject nonsense.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Did they re-register? 0.o That user must have a small war going on with Stack Overflow.

Comment: @cybermonkey: not sure what you mean; the last series was all done as 'anonymous'; e.g. they don't have an account at all. Anonymous, unregistered accounts can suggest edits too, but the spam prevention measures take this into account.

Comment: @cybermonkey: I also haven't seen anything new; all the attempts I've rejected have been posted at least 30 minutes ago.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, ok. Might be a good idea to mark this as `status-completed`, since it's been done.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, if you reject such edits as *spam or vandalism* then that information feeds back to the spam protection measures.

That is in *addition* to the normal suggested edit bans for registered accounts; repeated rejections mean the user will be (temporarily) blocked from suggesting more edits.

Please do reject all these edits; you as the post author get a veto vote, which means a persistent spammer or vandal will be blocked all the faster.

Spam accounts like these are not banned, by the way. Moderators will just destroy the account altogether. There is no point in keeping their contributions, after all; Flexo has already taken care of this specific account. Account destruction includes auto-deletion of all their "content".

Comment: Updated the question title and body. This user should just be banned.

Comment: @cybermonkey: the user account has been destroyed already. No need to ban, that implies their contributions were worth preserving.

Comment: Thanks for that; the user was getting on my nerves!

Comment: Also, in the future just flag one of your posts (or one of theirs), point to what's going on, and we can destroy trolls like this and hobble their ability to create new accounts. I'll also want to review all of the suggested edits to make sure no reviewers approved any of them. If someone did, they'll be taking a long vacation from review.

Comment: @BradLarson: I haven't found any yet, but I am not sure I caught all the suggested edits involved. So far, a little faith in reviewers has been restored.

Comment: @Brad I think I checked over all of them in this instance and amazingly didn't hand out any candy as a result.

Comment: @Flexo After the first couple of edit rejects, any edits from that account were shown with the message 'our system has detected this edit as possible spam. please review carefully'. I guess that this 'forces' even robo-reviewers to properly review.

Comment: @cybermonkey: you'd be surprised...