# Must we use Imgur for images?

Tags: discussion, support, images

I [put in a request to exterminate a user earlier today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277834/please-destroy-this-user), and as my request was fulfilled I flagged my question asking for the [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag to be edited into the question.

My flag was marked as 'helpful' and the tag was inserted, but however the *images in the question [were re-uploaded to Stack Exchange's Imgur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/277834/revisions).*

I use the `puush` screenshot capture program in order to upload my screenshots, and as I increasingly use Stack Overflow at college, where Imgur is blocked.
In questions when I insert an image, I always replace the link referring to the image at Stack Exchange's Imgur to the link that the `puush` program provides.

Whilst I know a few good reasons *why* images are automatically copied across to Stack Exchange's Imgur, ***is is a 'good' idea to change my images to Imgur?***

Is it a rule on Stack Overflow/Meta that we must use Imgur for images?

Comment: Images hosted on a lot of other sites can disappear pretty quickly. When those images disappear, questions and answers can become useless. I don't see a retention policy on the puush web site, but Stack Exchange has a Pro account at Imgur, which means their images will stay around pretty much indefinitely. It might be worth it for you to find out who sets your school's policy, and find out if they can make an exception for stack.imgur.com.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I've been planning to do so for ages, I've just never got the chance. They also block most Stack Exchange sites as 'forums' (cringes) so I've been meaning to get them unblocked also. The puush service holds images indefinitely but starts removing old ones when the account's storage has been reached (200MB for free users and unlimited for Pro users).

Comment: So, the original images are now gone, and your question is now left with dead links to images, with an empty box rendered instead of the image.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it a rule on Stack Overflow/Meta that we must use Imgur for images?

There is no such rule.

Our upload tool will use imgur by default, but if you have an existing image on the web that you want to use directly, you can just use that (using the markdown image syntax):

```
![image alt](http://example.com/path/to/image.jpg "image title")
```

Or:

```
![image alt][1]

[1]: http://example.com/path/to/image.jpg "image title"
```

The reason we like using imgur is that it is a known quantity and images on it are more likely to stay around than possibly those on other hosts.

Comment: Then I take it that editing a question solely to convert the images to Imgur are bad edits? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/277834/revisions for an example. User `gunr2171` only edited the question to move the images to Imgur and 'make them clickable'.

Comment: Given that we have seen image hosting services like the one in the edit disappear, there is good reason to make such edits. This is particularly true for image hosting services that only hold images for a limited amount of time (for example, some delete items that are 60 days old).

Comment: @cybermonkey: I'd have made the exact same edit had I noticed you didn't host the images on Imgur. Stack Exchange has a vested interest in keeping the images at Imgur hosted indefinitely. If Puush ever went out of business the images would be gone. If Imgur were to go out of business before SE did, SE would migrate those images.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Oded. What about copyrighted content?

Comment: What about them, @Pacerier? Why would they fall under anything other than our usual copyrighted content policy (meaning - if you are the copyright holder - go knock yourself out, if you are not - get permission from the copyright holder)?

Comment: And as it happens Puush has now gone out of business but imgur is still up.

Answer (score 12):

There is a strong preference for using the Stack Exchange Imgur account for uploading images for the simple reason that this is the only method guaranteed to be available (at least as long as the sites themselves exist). Images on free hosters tend to expire at some point, images on personal hosting can get unavailable after a while as well.

Fixing this months or years later when the images aren't available is very annoying. Using the SE image upload functionality prevents the whole issue.

There is no hard rule on this as far as I know, though.

Answer (score -1):

The Imgur used by Stack Overflow isn't the usual Imgur, but a specific instance paid for by Stack Exchange, probably with a Service Level Agreement.

This may as well be equivalent to Stack Exchange hosting their own image service, meaning that if Imgur were to ever fail, that the data uploaded to the service would likely be

1. transferrable/recoverable.
2. owned by Stack Exchange.

This means that images hosted on stack.imgur.com have no difference then text, other then the known accessibility problems, and data storage issues. So those images, rather then those hosted off site, are known to be available for as long as Stack Exchange is able to pay the bills.