# Is a blatant request for software piracy a valid reason to ban a user?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054651/how-may-i-find-keygen-of-the-crysis-2, which I flagged for moderator attention as "This question is asking how to commit software piracy." (The author quickly removed the question once I commented on it and flagged it, but you can tell from the title what the question was.) I've since learned that while questions about how to commit software piracy are certainly off-topic and should be closed as such, [they are not *per se* a reason to delete a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277790/2314532).

But that's not why I'm asking a question now. You see, when I flagged that question, I also suggested that the user who asked that question should perhaps be banned as well. My reasoning was that anyone who asks about pirated software is not likely to be the kind of person who will make Stack Overflow a better site. But now I'm wondering: did I go too far in suggesting that that user be banned? Is a blatant request for software piracy a valid reason to ban a user? Or should we say "Well, he's probably young and stupid, give him a chance and he may grow up and become a useful, contributing user of the site"?

Comment: It's not wrong to cast the flag so that a mod can see the situation and take the action they feel is appropriate.  Just be prepared to accept the fact that they're not necessarily going to ban someone just because you asked them to.

Comment: My guess is that mods would first just reach out to the user and let them know.  They would consider banning the user if these piracy-related posts continue.

Comment: How does asking about software piracy lead to the conclusion that they can't contribute to the site in a useful way?

Comment: @JoeW asking such a wildly off-topic question on SO is indeed a strong indicator the user is going to be useless - not always, but probably most of the time.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I was just wondering how a question about software piracy was different then another off-topic question.

Comment: @Joe it's not really much different, that's true. A suspension would probably not be warranted

Comment: @Joe W: "young and stupid" (as the OP says) - you would have to be incredibly naïve at best to think it's OK to ask how to pirate software on a community revolving around software development.

Comment: @BoltClock: alas, cynicism rules. One of the sites I attend to concerns *typography*, and it's not uncommon to encounter posts of world renowned type designers. It's also not uncommon to see posts asking "where can I download [insert expensive design font name here] for free plz respond asap". In addition, it is *also* not uncommon to find such persons 'defend' themselves with arguments such as ".. but I am a poor student and I need this particular font for my design".

Comment: @jongware Where exactly does cynicism fit in that recognizable story? Honest interest!

Comment: @Gimby: In my experience, any online community *will* attract both the smart, the interested, and the helpful as well as the lazy, the stupid, and the dishonest. [And you shall be thanked for that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296913/what-should-i-do-about-a-user-that-im-trying-to-help-and-is-calling-me-stupid). (For >10K: [you've all seen this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733421/i-need-help-in-solving-this-program).)

Comment: @Jongware I see where you're getting at. You see cynicism where I see negativism, but its two sides of the same coin really.

Answer (score 12):

You should never suggest a user be disciplined in certain way in public. It has no bearing on how they will actually be disciplined, and it has the potential to cause more harm than good.

Feel free to flag and ask that the user be 'banned' in a flag; but you shouldn't counsel that way in public (especially if you don't know what the actual procedures are for suspending a user).

It's also worth noting that we don't ban specific users.  We suspend users, and we ban IP addresses.

We ban IP Addresses in case of outright spam or abuse from that IP address.

It's also worth noting that *we* (the moderators) don't ban IP addresses, the system or the community team does based on flags acted upon or specific requests that they can then double check.

Answer (score 8):

Meh, don't worry. Just trust the moderators. They will sort it out.

I've suggested that a user be banned or suspended in a number of flags over the years. In hindsight, suspension may not always have been as warranted as I felt at the time - and luckily, the mods often enough didn't follow up on my request.

Flag comments are expected to sometimes be fuelled by the emotion of the moment, and not always perfectly objective.

I'm sure moderators won't just blindly do whatever we suggest in flags; they're going to use their guidelines to decide what needs to be done.

That's what we elect them for, after all.